# Flow is going back to first screen after clicking FINISH button on screen component

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow, salesforce-flow

I have a screen flow that checks for a decision and based on the decision it shows the respective screen. When I select an option, it properly navigates to the next screen. However when I click on FINISH in the last screen it looks back to the first screen of the flow.

I am calling the flow via lightning component embedded in a quick action modal.

Comment: Can you confirm how is this flow called? Can you check debugging if the flow is again called

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Flow is called from a lightning component using lightning:flow. When I debug from the flow window it works fine.

Comment: When embedded in a page or other component that doesn't actually close the flow, flows automatically restart. This is standard behaviour. You need to make sure your component listens for a state change from the flow it started and hides the flow again on finish.

Comment: @PhilW I am calling this flow using Standard Quick Action and overriding its lightning component that in turn calls flow using. lightning:flow. Do you mean that is this scenario also it will automatically restart? Ideally the flow is embedded on the quick action modal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a component that uses `lightning:flow`, it is your responsibility to ensure that you "close" the flow UI when the user presses Finish.

This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:flow/documentation) and I've reproduced it here for clarity:

> Each flow component includes navigation buttons (Back, Next, Pause, and Finish), which navigate within the flow. By default, when the flow finishes, the component reloads the first screen for a new interview. To customize what happens when the flow finishes, add an event handler for the onstatuschange action when status contains FINISHED. For an example, see [Control a Flow’s Finish Behavior in a Lightning Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_flow_onfinish.htm).